# Practical applications of the $L^p$ norm when $p \neq 1,2,\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, numerical-methods

I'm roughly familiar with the concept of $L^p$ norms -- what they represent and how they are computed -- though I am far from educated in functional analysis in general. For reasons that are more or less obvious, in many practical applications, the $L^2$ norm is used (ie, optimization, etc). One also sees the $L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$ norms used from time to time.

However, rarely do I see any mention of, say, the $L^3$ norm, or really any $L^p$ norm where $p$ is something other than 1, 2 or $\infty$ (or, in some interpretations, 0).

Are there any algorithms or applications that have exploited the other norms? Does convergence in an $L^p$ sense mean something different for these values of $p$? Is there any value of $p$ that can lead to a property not obtainable by $p=1,2,\infty$?

Comment: Relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28147/why-do-we-care-about-lp-spaces-besides-p-1-p-2-and-p-infinity

Comment: The $L_0$-"norm", (a misnomer since it is not a norm in the usual sense), which counts the number of non-zero components of a vector, is a convenient notation to deal with sparsity in compressed sensing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example not mentioned in the MO thread: the $L^4$ norm appears in the [Ginzburg-Landau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory#section_1) formula for the energy of superconductor.

More generally: we want nonlinear variational models to describe phenomena which do not obey linear superposition. Minimization of $L^2$ norm leads to linear PDE. Minimization of $L^1$ and $L^\infty $ norms leads to badly degenerate things that are barely PDE at all. The norms $L^4$ and $L^{\rm dimension}$ emerge as attractive alternatives.

Comment: Along these lines, could seeking alternative norms for minimization be a general strategy for solving other problems?

Comment: @EdGorcenski One usually minimizes an *energy functional*, which is not necessarily a norm (i.e., neither homogeneity nor triangle inequality are required). But energy functionals tend to have bits of $L^p$ norms in them. A [Google Scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22energy+functional%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=) shows that $L^2$ and $L^4$ are the most popular ingredients.